# jOOQ Converter expression for single column in table

Tags: java, sql, jooq, codegen

I have a custom `EnumConverter` setup and I want to use it only for a single column in a specific table to generate the POJOs.

```
<forcedType>
    <name>foo.bar.MyTableStatus</name>
    <expression>mytable.status</expression>
</forcedType>
```

I've tried several permutations, but the only one I got working was a generic

```
<forcedType>
    <name>foo.bar.MyTableStatus</name>
    <expression>.*\.status</expression>
</forcedType>
```

But this converts *all* status columns in all tables, which is not what I'm looking for.

I've read the docs, the XSD and there's nothing explaining against what regular expression to match. Is it `table/column`? `table.column`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original configuration looks almost correct to me:

```xml
<expression>mytable.status</expression>
```

Fully qualified means that the schema is also part of the name, i.e. you should try either of these:

```xml
<expression>.*\.mytable\.status</expression>
<expression>myschema\.mytable\.status</expression>
```

Also, be sure to use the correct casing. Case-insensitive regexes can also be used:

```xml
<expression>(?i:.*\.mytable\.status)</expression>
<expression>(?i:myschema\.mytable\.status)</expression>
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas, first option didn't work. I was missing the schema I guess.